# Why am I being asked to sign in at stack sites (e.g. Ask Ubuntu) when I'm already signed in?

Tags: support, login

I've already posted there in the past.

**Evidence I'm signed-in to StackExchange**:

1. Heck I'm posting right here right now.
2. StackExchange menu dropdown is notifying me about StackOverflow and
   Magento questions/answer/comments.

So, why am I being asked to sign in there?

And by the way, I'm asking this because this kind of thing happens way too often. It never seems to happen with StackOverflow, but often with some of the other sites.

Also, the StackExchange dropdown at AskUbuntu doesn't show the data from my other StackExchange site memberships. Even though I got there by navigating through that menu from here. Why is my logged-in state not being "forwarded"?

I'm not sure how to reproduce this bug, as it seems to affect sites randomly. I'm sure I'm not the only one experiencing it.

Here is the Ask Ubuntu StackExchange dropdown I'm talking about, except now that I signed in there it does show my other StackExchange data:

[image: Ask ubuntu StackExchange dropdown]

I arrived at Ask Ubuntu by using that search field "Find a Stack Exchange community" on this page (the page of this question) at meta.stackexchange.com. Obviously, I'm signed in here. So it's strange to be asked to sign in there. I initially arrived at Ask Ubuntu today through a Google search. After discovering I wasn't signed in, I tried going there from here. Shouldn't I be automatically signed in to all StackExchange sites where I am a member?

Using latest Google Chrome on Windows 8.1.

Edit:
My first time signing out of StackExchange:

[image: Sign out screen]

I don't see magento.stackexchange or dba.stackexchange, but I suppose that is because they are under the overall stackexchange cookie umbrella.

Signing out and signing back in now seems to have be signed in to all StackExchange sites, regardless of domain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short version is that as of a few months ago, you *should* be getting logged in network-wide, but there are a couple cases where that's not going to happen. For example, in Safari. Although even then, once you log in on a domain, the login should at least stick. If you're not using Safari, make sure third-party cookies are allowed.

If you clean your cookies for all Stack Exchange domains (stackoverflow.com, stackexchange.com, superuser.com, askubuntu.com, serverfault.com, mathoverflow.net, and stackapps.com) and log in, does the behaviour you're seeing persist?

If so, we're gonna need some more info here. What browser are you using? Can you add some screenshots of what you're seeing? (Not sure what you mean by "the StackExchange dropdown at AskUbuntu doesn't show the data from my other StackExchange site memberships", in particular). If you get logged out without actually logging out... can you think of anything that you do that reproduces that? A few dates/times of recent logouts would be helpful as well so we can look through traffic logs and try to piece together what happened.

Thanks, and I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

P.S. I should clarify. You should be getting logged in everywhere *when you explicitly log in*. We unfortunately weren't able to grandfather everyone's existing sessions into full network-wide logins, so you may need to log out and log back in on any domain if you haven't explicitly logged in in a few months.

Comment: I added browser/OS into.
I also added an image of the StackExchange dropdown I'm referring to (with my personalized data showing). I'm not sure what I'm supposed to call it. I didn't specifically "get logged out," but I am logged into StackExchange.

Comment: @ButtleButkus My money is on you just not having logged in since before we switched over to the new login system we have now. If you log out and log back in, do you end up logged in to both stackexchange.com sites and Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: I bought this computer a few months ago, and probably logged into StackOverflow fairly soon after that. At that point, I'm not sure if I had to log into the other stack sites manually. But I just posted on the physics site today and I'm pretty sure I did not explicitly log in there. Yet I had to log in to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @ButtleButkus meta.stackexchange.com and physics.stackexchange.com both live on the same second-level domain, so they use the same account session (and we were able to easily upgrade those).

Comment: I've never logged out of this site before. How do you do it?

Comment: Ahh, I see. I have dealt with that same cookie issue myself.

Comment: @ButtleButkus Hit "log out" in the SE dropdown (same one you put in your screenshot)

Comment: That seems to have worked. Hopefully I never have to sign out again. By the way, I'm interested to learn how they achieved the multi-domain cookie. Is there a blog about this?

Comment: @ButtleButkus I keep meaning to write one, but there's never time. Basically, once you auth on one domain, we fire off ajax requests to the other six and they come back with a Set-Cookie header for that domain. (Which is also why this doesn't really work in Safari - no 3rd-party cookies under any circumstances.)

Comment: @ButtleButkus Glad to hear it worked, though. =) Ping me if you see any other login issues.

Comment: Thanks. And congrats on the good work on that cookie umbrella. It works great, actually.